# Trouble adding extra CFLAGS with $< in makefile

Tags: makefile, kernel

We have a kernel module that has its own `makefile` which works correctly.

```
all::
    $(MAKE) -C $(KSRC) M=$(PWD) modules
```

Sometimes we need `make` to output a `.lst` by adding `-Wa,-ahlms` to `CFLAGS`. In our `makefile` we add `EXTRA_CFLAGS += -Wa,-ahlms=$<.lst`.

However, this doesn't work, because `$<` is empty at this time, and `$$<` will not work also. Does anybody know how we can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Variables are defined in two ways (for our purposes) in make: simple:

```
FOO := $<
```

where the right-hand side is evaluated immediately, so this sets `FOO` to the empty string.  And recursive:

```
FOO = $<
```

where the right-hand side is not evaluated until the variable is used; this sets `FOO` to the value `$<` and then later when `$(FOO)` is expanded, the value of `$<` at that time will be expanded.

Clearly, the latter is what you want if you want to include automatic variables into your variable value.  When you use the `+=` operator, the type of the variable (simple vs. recursive) is inferred from the previous setting of the variable (if there is no previous setting then recursive is the default).  You don't show how `EXTRA_CFLAGS` is set, but if you're having this problem then someone must have set it to be simple:

```
EXTRA_CFLAGS :=
```

If you can't change that to use a recursive setting, then the only way you can do what you want is to explicitly use `=` not `+=` when you assign it:

```
EXTRA_CFLAGS = -Wa,-ahlms=$<.lst
```

If you really want to add to an existing value all you can do is make extra variables, like this:

```
PREVIOUS_EXTRA_CFLAGS := $(EXTRA_CFLAGS)
EXTRA_CFLAGS = $(PREVIOUS_EXTRA_CFLAGS) -Wa,-ahlms=$<.lst
```